# How to stop getting this "not found" url routing error in django

Tags: python, django

Though both links are exactly the same, I keep receiving a "Page Not Found at /accounts/login/next?" error whenever I click my link. What's the error in my code? 'explore' works, but 'happening' doesn't! Please help!

views.py

```
def explore(request):
    return render(request, 'explore.html')

def happening(request):
    return render(request, 'happening.html')
```

html template

```
  <div id="happening_log">
     <a style= "padding-left:5px" href="{% url 'happening' 
          %}">Happening</a>
  </div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.explore, name='explore'),
     path('<user__name>/', views.home, name='home'),
     path('happening/', views.happening, name='happening'),
]
```

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/happening/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
[name='explore']
<user__name>/ [name='home']
/happening/ [name='happening']
users/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: It seems like you're being redirected to login but you don't have those urls enabled? Did you paste here the entire `views.py`?

Comment: Do you have a login_required decorator or something in your views? there must be a reason why you're being redirected to log in. Is that what you want?

Comment: could you add the **urls.py** file from project level

Comment: You have been redirecting to your login page, but your login url is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a registration/login.html file in your project site?
The url, http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/happening/ is accessing login template, so you have to make a default registration/login.html or another login like like below;

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user and user.profile.status == 'WORKING':
                auth.login(request, user)

                if user.profile.passwd:
                    return redirect('myprofile')
                else:
                    return redirect('password')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I fixed it by reserving the order of   : path('<user__name>/', views.home, name='home'),
     path('happening/', views.happening, name='happening'),